# Who (name of the science) researches meaning communicated through arts?

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics, semantics, language, art

John I. Saeed in his famous textbook defines the Semantic as "Semantics is the study of meaning communicated through language". So - what is name for the science that researches meaning as communicated through art? Does aesthetics do this? I guess that aesthetics is more about form and less about meaning (content)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Phenomenonlogy and Hermeneutics of Art. But I also suggest reading Adorno on Aesthetic Theory. Adorno addresses Form as well as Meaning of Art.

Comment: I would also say it is 'Aesthetics'.